# Why list is not changing when adding a element during debug the program?

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

I have created this program.

```
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add(1);
    l.add(5);
    l.add(112);

    Iterator i = l.iterator();      
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(i.next());

    }
    Iterator ii = l.iterator();

    while(ii.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(ii.next());

    }
```

When I am running this program on debug.

The debug point is on `Iterator i = l.iterator();`  .

At this point , I have added an integer in the list by going in the variables tab in eclipse.

I have added `Integer.valueof(34);`.

Now when i completely run this program, it prints

```
1
5
112
1
5
112
```

Why the 2nd iterator is not printing `34` . And neither it gives me an `ConcurrentModificationException` exception.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be much easier if you'd just show the code *including* the addition of 34. It's a pain for people to have to reproduce this by setting breakpoints etc. Please edit the code to a short but *complete* example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Looks like you're lucky. If you'd actually described what you'd done in any detail, it would have been much easier to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're directly changing `l.elementData[3]` from `null` to an `Integer`. Since you're directly -- and inconsistently -- messing around with the internals of the class, it's not guaranteed to continue to behave in accordance with its contract.

On my implementation, adding an element also requires changing `l.size`. The fail-fast mechanism relies on `l.modCount`, which needs to be incremented.

In other words, to mimic `ArrayList.add()` manually, you need to examine the source code of your implementation, and carry out all the steps that the real implementation would.

Comment: Yes.I am doing that.Still can you give me some technical reason why it is happening like this?

Comment: Technical reason: `size` determines the last element used in the array, so anything beyond will be ignored. `modCount` is incremented on modifications and used to raise ConcurrentModificationExceptions.

Comment: hey..thanks..I was not changing size. And when i change size I got ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentModificationExceptions are fail-fast. So they are on a best effort basis. Essentially not guaranteed to throw up immediately.

Comment: Doesn't "fail-fast" mean that it should fail fast, i.e. immediately?

Comment: from [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) : Fail-fast operations throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness:

Comment: There you go. This *implementation* of fail-fast is best-effort (making it fail-not-reliably-fast)

Comment: Yup. That is what I mentioned in my post as well. :)